# How can sex lead to a boost in performance for competitive sports for men?

Tags: biology, humans, sex

Many believe that sex before a competition can have a negative impact on performance in combat, speed and strength sports in males. Athletes from strength and speed sports showed decreased performance up to two hours after sexual intercourse. The most likely cause of this is lower testosterone levels in men after sex and the resulting reduction in aggressiveness.

For this world, I want the myth to be a reality for males, but in the opposite way. Instead of decreasing effectiveness, intercourse leads to a small but noticeable boost in testosterone, leading to a slightly heightened state of aggressiveness and awareness. This would be useful before going into strength and speed competitions, or warfare. The first thought on how to do this would be to link a higher rate of endorphins to increased rate of testosterone. However, anything that gave  pleasure, such as eating, smoking, etc, would cause a man to be in a constant higher state of aggression. This would be bad for the individual's body and for society on a bigger level.

How can I get around this factor without negatively affecting males over the long term?

Comment: This question is not worded well.  Do you mean ***men***?  Because you're saying you mean everyone but then you talk about stuff specific to men.  Please edit to be very clear you really only mean men, or take out the stuff that only applies to men.  Your choice.

Comment: Heh heh! Anticipation could improve performance for many hours *before* the sex.

Comment: I've heard the opposite. Sex leads to increased testosterone and improved athletic performance in men. Do you have studies that show otherwise?

Comment: Seems like an obvious logical flaw in "Athletes from strength and speed sports showed decreased performance up to two hours after sexual intercourse."  But sex is athletic: I would wager those athletes would show the same performance decrease if they'd done any other sort of exercise of similar intensity two hours before their competition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evolutionary traits.

Evolution is about the fittest, and the fittest is also the most energy efficient. So our bodies are constantly adapting to be as efficient as possible. That is why muscles disappear when you stop using them.

For humans sex is more than procreation, it's also a social endeavor. The male is encouraged to stay and help the female to ensure the children have the best chance in life to grow up and reproduce themselves. So the male caring for the female is more efficient.

Imagine a scenario where, as part of the mating ritual and social convention, the male is expected to find food and luxuries for the female. Both to get her strength up for childbearing and increasing the chance she stays with him for repeated sex (as pregnancy usually doesn't happen instantly). This means the male needs a higher aggression to achieve his goals.

Additionally in humans a higher testosterone level increases socially accepted behaviour, as humans can achieve more social status that way than through violence. So the male could use this higher testosterone level to make social commitments, warning males that the female is taken and warning females that the male is already providing for one female.

Edit: I'll see if I can look it up, but does sex not already improve athletic capabilities? You aren't allowed to have sex shortly before a competition right? And there are advantages I know about like how regular sex improves your immune system, social capabilities, reduces social disorders and will increase sexual markers such as women who can have up to 25% increase in breast size from regular sex.

One caveat for those advantages: they really only work when the one having sex does it because he/she wants sex, not if they do it to achieve something else.

Answer (score 2):

Some hormones in the body fluids exchanged during sexual intercourse (between a male and a female) could somehow react, and produce another hormone which amplifies the aggressiveness and awareness of the individual. Depending on how you want the myth to play out, this hormone could work for males, females or both. The human body would decompose this hormone fairly quickly, so the effect is only short term (again, up to you how to decide how long the effect should last). Sex between two males or two females wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is contained within the question itself:  According to the version of the myth you cite, performance is impaired after sex because testosterone reserves are depleted and it falls to below baseline level.  If the additional testosterone released during sex instead remains present and active in your blood, then that would provide enhanced performance.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers:  modify the biology so that sexual climax releases whatever chemicals, proteins, stimulants, etc.  you wish.  Maybe this is an evolutionary trait because a predatory species which feeds on your posthumans is strongly attracted to pheremones emitted during sexual activity.  The posthumans then developed post-coital megastrength (or reaction time) to fight off these predators.